# How to Animate <tr> using slideDown() Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, django, forms, jquery-animate

I have used the below code in my Django template, which prints the song title and a download button in a .

(PS: "songs" is an array of song, that is coming from a Django view )

I want to apply animation to every row , that is printed. I have heard of slideDown() in jquery, but don't know how to use it.

**(In current situation: All the songs are displayed all at once, I want to display them, one by one using animation (slideDown())**

```
                   {% if songs %}
                        <table class="table text-justify" style="margin-left:0px;">
                            <tbody>
                                {% for song in songs %}
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{song.title}}</td>
                                <td><a class="btn btn-block btn-success" href="/search/search/?song_id={{song.id}}">Download</a></td>
                              </tr>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          {% endif %}
                          {% if ERROR %}
                          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            {{ERROR}}
                          </div>
                          {% endif %}
```

I tried the following :

(but didn't work )

```
                   {% if songs %}


                        <script>

                         $('tr').slideDown(); 

                         </script>



                        <table class="table text-justify" style="margin-left:0px;">
                            <tbody>
                                {% for song in songs %}
                              <tr>
                                <td>{{song.title}}</td>
                                <td><a class="btn btn-block btn-success" href="/search/search/?song_id={{song.id}}">Download</a></td>
                              </tr>
                              {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                          {% endif %}
                          {% if ERROR %}
                          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                            {{ERROR}}
                          </div>
                          {% endif %}
```

Also, "songs" array is calculated after submitting a form, using a post method.

Please help.

Comment: As you've found `.slideDown` can't be used on a `tr` (or `td`).  One work around is to put a `div` inside the `tr` and slide that down

Comment: Tried with <div> too, didn't work. All songs are getting displayed at once. I want it in one by one.

Comment: But do they slide down?  Even if they slide down all at once?

Comment: They'll only slide down if a) they're hidden to start with and b) you run the .slideDown *after* you add the rows.  The code you've provided does neither of these (already shown and slideDown before they exist)